# Inversion - Sentence starting with rarely

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

This is from my English Cambridge Proficiency Book. In Unit 8 about inversions, I had to rewrite the sentence:

Original sentence:

**It is very difficult for town centre redevelopment to achieve a harmonious balance between old and new**

My answer:

Rarely is it easy for town centre redevelopment to achieve a harmonious balance between old and new

Correct question (according to the book):

Rarely do/will/can town centre redevelopments achieve a harmonious balance between old and new.

I wonder why my answer isn't acceptable.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my sentence?

Thanks

Comment: Your sentence is fine.  It uses what's called the enduing present tense to illustrate an ongoing situation or general truth.

Comment: I am wondering why both you and they used *rarely* since it doesn't appear in the original sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not only perfectly acceptable, but a more accurate rendering than the one they want.

In their answer they have tacitly applied an implication (which is not even a logical implication, but a material one) that 'X is difficult' => 'X occurs rarely'. I think this is inappropriate in a grammar book.

Comment: But his answer also equates 'difficult' & 'rarely', so why is it better?

Comment: True, it does. But it reverses the "difficult" into "easy", rather than omitting it altogether.

Comment: Point taken; previously overlooked; & now I agree!